# Why are there missing opcodes when using the disassembler on bytecode from the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, opcode

I'm using the disassembler from [go-ethereum repo](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) which fails on about 20% of the bytecode from the blockchain with missing/unknown opcodes.
The disassembler on [Etherscan](http://etherscan.io) fails as well.

Is there an up-to-date disassembler with complete opcode tables that can be used? Am I doing something wrong?

Examples of failed disassembly -

1. [0x52ecf69544784165101e76a682eeea642e72584d](http://etherscan.io/address/0x52ecf69544784165101e76a682eeea642e72584d#code)
2. [0x4432979c7c6bdd19f9ef20787c4ac9cc9710667b](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4432979c7c6bdd19f9ef20787c4ac9cc9710667b#code)

Comment: It looks like whatever disassembler etherscan was using got fixed? If you click the "Switch To Opcodes View" button/link, it shows you a disassembly.

Answer (score 4):

I've written another disassembler to help me understand some of this stuff, and because I really wanted offsets beside the instructions. You can find it here.

https://github.com/jamiehale/evm_disasm

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.